# JQuery to check checkbox in td based on value in different td

Tags: jquery, jsp

have the following code and the last td value bound to `${subscription.subscriptionStatus}` has integer value `1` or `0`.

Would like to do it if the above subscriptionStatus has value 1, want check `checkbox` in the first `td`, and if value is 0, don't want to check it.

What can be the easiest way and sorry if this may duplicate another question?

```
<td class="leftBorder" style="width:20px">
    <input type="checkbox" class="subscriptionCheck" name="subscription_${entry.key.typeTitle}_${status.index}" 
            value="${subscription.patronSolicitationId}" id="subscription_${entry.key.typeTitle}_${status.index}"/>
</td>
<td>${subscription.displaySubscriptionName}</td>
<td>
    <input type="hidden" value="${subscription.subscriptionStatus}"/>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function ($) {
    //set the checked property of all elements with class subscriptionCheck
    $('.subscriptionCheck').prop('checked', function () {
        //if the value of input field in the last cell of the current row is 1 then return true
        return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:last-child input').val() == '1'
    })
})
```